# Cannot complete installation of AMPPS on Mac with Big Sur

Tags: php, html, css, web-development-server, ampps

I have not been able to install AMPPS on my MacBook Pro with Big Sur. Does anyone know if a compatible version of AMPPS is expected? If not, what is a good development server for web projects with PHP and Javascript on the Mac? Thanks

Comment: what error did you get when installing AMPPS on your macbook

Comment: I don't get an error. The program just wouldn't load. It was trying to do it for over an hour when I gave up. Then I saw online comments from people with the same problem. I'm guessing it is because AMPPS is not compatible with Mac Big Sur.

Comment: Please share more details. What **exactly** is not working? What have you tried to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

AMPPS does not currently support Big Sur.

There's a [post](https://www.softaculous.com/board/index.php?tid=17221&title=Ammps_won%27t_start_in_macos_Big_Sur) on their forum without any reply from the developers and over 20k views.

Comment: any recommendations?